# Help identify Mystery Modules (RF?)

Tags: rf

I inherited a box of parts a hobbyist had left behind.  In the box was a WIDE variety of stuff.  I have identified most everything except three small (abt 15mm cube) modules. They are 3-pin and intended for PCB mount.  They are metal shielded except for a small opening.  I have three.  One slightly larger and two identical. The two smaller ones were in an unopened Jameco bag.  There are no markings or numbers except a single large digit.  There was nothing on the bag. Here is a photo [image: mystery modules].
Does anyone know what they are?

Comment: Electret microphones?

Comment: Infrared receivers with internal amplifier, put into a metal casing for better electrical noise resistance.

Comment: Indeed looks like IR receiver. Measure which pin is connected to the case then apply +5 V to the pin opposite to that ground pin. Then connect a LED and a resistor to the middle pin and use a TV remote to send an IR signal. If you're lucky the LED will blink.

Comment: @Janka, I tried searching Jameco for "infrared" and "receiver" and could not find anything visually similar.

Comment: The Sharp GP1U7 series is similar and you should be able to find a datasheet of that one.

Comment: @Janka Sharp GP1U7 looks like an exact match for the smaller two.  Why not submit an answer?

Comment: I found the [GP1U77 datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/42831/SHARP/GP1U772R/+32J43UO.vRPbpyA/1DEza+/datasheet.pdf).  I wonder if the '2' means it is a GP1U772 (36.7 KHz)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These could be a lot of things, but my first guess is they are IR receivers.  That fits with the three pins.  They are power, ground, and data output.  The data outputs of these things tends to be open collector, pulled low when IR with the right modulation frequency is received.

These modules contain active circuitry that looks for modulation in the received IR over a narrow frequency range.  Individual units are set to a fixed frequency.  The available frequencies are usually in the 30 to 45 kHz range.

After a few cycles of the modulation frequency is detected, the output is pulled low.  The IR transmitter sends bursts usually about 10-30 modulation cycles long.  The data is encoded in the lengths of the bursts and the gaps between them.  This is how most TV remotes, for example, work.